# change the position of the ion-refresher

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to reverse the direction of the `ion-refresher`, but switching the position doesn't seem to work like it does on the `Ion-Infinite-Scroll`

```
<ion-refresher [position]="isReverse ? 'bottom' : 'top'" pullingIcon="arrow-dropdown"  pullingText="Pull to refresh"
  refreshingSpinner="circles"  refreshingText="Refreshing..." (ionRefresh)="refresh($event)">
</ion-refresher>
<ion-infinite-scroll *ngIf="!isPagingComplete" (ionInfinite)="doInfinite($event)" [position]="isReverse ? 'bottom' : 'top'">
    <ion-infinite-scroll-content></ion-infinite-scroll-content>
  </ion-infinite-scroll>
<div *ngIf="isNotSliding">
  <template *ngFor="let entity of entityList" [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngOutletContext]="{entity: entity}">
  </template>    
</div>
<div *ngIf="!isNotSliding">
  <ion-item-sliding class="page-list-sliding-item" *ngFor="let entity of entityList" #item>
    <ion-item class="page-list-inner-item" (click)="config.onItemClick(entity)" >
      <template [ngTemplateOutlet]="template" [ngOutletContext]="{entity: entity}"></template>
    </ion-item>
    <ion-item-options side="right">
      <button ion-button color="danger"  *ngIf="config && config.canDelete" (click)="delete(entity.id)">
        <ion-icon name="trash"></ion-icon>Delete
      </button>
      <button ion-button color="dark" >
        <ion-icon name="more"></ion-icon>More
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>
  </ion-item-sliding>
</div>
```

How can I reverse the scroll on the `Ion-Refresher`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ion-refresher` component is a really special one.
It will always be placed at the top of the nearest `ion-content` component.

There is no default option or configuration to make the reverse `ion-refresher` possible.

Comment: Interesring so there’s no known way to invert the direction of the pull

Comment: I wish we could override the parent container instead of directly into the ion-app